# Why does $\left\| {T(x)} \right\| \le \left\| T \right\|\left\| x \right\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X \to Y$ be a linear functional .Why does $\left\| {T(x)} \right\| \le \left\| T \right\|\left\| x \right\|$?(I dont understand Why does this inquality is hold)-thanks.

Comment: State the definition of $\|T\|$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, for $X\ne \{0\}$, $\|T\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\ne 0}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}=\sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|\ge \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$, for all $x$ with $\|x\|\ne 0$. Together with $\|T0\|=0=\|T\|\|0\|$, you get the desired result.

If $X=\{0\}$, as pointed out by gerw in the comment below, linear $T$ is by definition the null or $0$ operator, and its norm is $0$. The inequality trivially holds and is an equality.

Comment: One should note that this definition is only valid if $X \ne \{0\}$.

Comment: @gerw: You are right. I just added that trivial case.

Comment: that \ni  in the first line is quite confusing...

Comment: @hjhjhj57: You meant "$\|x\|\ne 1$"? I just corrected the typo. Thank you. Please check.

Comment: No, the thing is you're using the symbol \ni as "such that." I'm aware some people use it like this, even though the symbol is nothing but \in backwards. I was just being picky...

Comment: In case $X = \{0\}$, $\|T\|$ should be defined to be $0$. Otherwise, it is not a norm on $L(X,Y)$.

Comment: @gerw: Why is $T$ not a norm if $\|T\|\ne 0$? We have $TX=0$. Which condition of norm does it violate if $\|T\|\ne 0$?

Comment: If $X = \{0\}$, the only linear operator is $T = 0$. By homogeneity, we have $2 \| T \| = \| T \|$, since $2 \, T = T$. Hence, $\|T\| = 0$.

Comment: @gerw: Yes, you are right. I thought of $T=0$ but refuted myself, as I thought $T$ defined as multiplication by any nonzero number could do. But on $\{0\}$ these operators are all null operators. I have corrected my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For $x = 0$, both sides are $0$ and the result follows trivially.

Suppose $x \neq 0$. By linearity of $T$ and considering $\alpha = \|x\| \in \mathbb{F}$, we have

$$T(x) = T(\alpha \cdot \frac{x}{\alpha}) = \alpha T(\frac{x}{\alpha})$$

and therefore

$$\|T(x)\| = \| \alpha T(\frac{x}{\alpha}) \| = \vert \alpha \vert \| T(\frac{x}{\alpha}) \|$$

Now since $\|\frac{x}{\alpha}\| = 1$, we have
$$\|T(\frac{x}{\alpha}) \| \leq \sup_{\|y\| = 1} \|T(y)\| = \|T\|$$

Finally we have
$$\|T(x)\| \leq \vert \alpha \vert \|T\| = \|T\|\|x\|$$